# What makes a file under the AppData\Roaming folder discoverable at command line?

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, path

I originally had an older version of node.js (0.10 dot something) installed on my Windows 7 system.  Then I installed cordova using npm.  When I typed *cordova* at the `cmd` prompt, the system was unable to find the corresponding command.  The file in question (*cordova*, with no file extension) is located in the following folder:

> %AppData%\Roaming\npm

I then realized that I was running an obsolete version of node, so I upgraded to node version 6.9.2.

Now, when I type *cordova* at the `cmd` prompt, the system finds the file!

What did the new version of node do to Windows during its installation to make this happen?  I checked, and the following folder was present as part of the `PATH` environment variable in the old and the new versions of node:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

**Update**, following comment from PanagiotisKanavos:

The node folder is in the `PATH` variable.  But while the Roaming\npm is not in path, the *cordova* file is still found.  In older version of node, the file was not discoverable, so I am attributing the change to the new version of node, but I am not sure.

**Close**

Thanks to a clue in a comment by [Borre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2962686/borre), I realized that node is actually adding the %AppData%\Roaming\npm path to the `PATH` variable, but it is doing so in the *user* environment.  I was checking the *system* `PATH` variable, and did not look at the user side.

Comment: There is no DOS prompt in Windows. Executables are located by looking in the current folder or the User and System PATH variables. If you couldn't run `cordova`, it means it wasn't in the path. You can find an executable's location with `where myexe`, eg `where cordova`.

Comment: Wait, you mention that the PATH contains `C:\Program Files\nodejs` yet cordova is located in `%AppData%\Roaming\npm`. That is, it's *not* in the path.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated question body and title.

Comment: I don't believe node is doing anything special, for me %AppData%\Roaming\npm is in the path variable.

Comment: @Borre Thank you! Please see my update.  I voted to close the question, rather than delete it, might help someone else.